# Index out of bounds error for UIView animation method

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an index out of bounds error, but I can't figure out why. The code compiles fine, but the error appears at the following line (animation):

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    private let contentView = UIView()
    private let logoView = UIImageView()
    private let buttonView = UIView()
    private var gameButtons = [RoundedButton]()
    private let scoreView = UIView()
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let recentScoreLabel = UILabel()
    private let highscoreLabel = UILabel()

    private let titles = [
        "Multiple Choice",
        "Image Quiz",
        "Right or wrong",
        "Emoji Riddle"

    ]

    private var recentScores = [Int]()
    private var highscores = [Int]()
    private var scoreIndex = 0
    private var timer = Timer()

    private var midXConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    private var leftConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    private var rightConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!

    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 128/255, blue: 185/255, alpha: 1.0)
        layoutView()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    func updateScores() {
        recentScores = [
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: multipleChoiceRecentscoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: imageQuizRecentscoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: rightWrongRecentscoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: emojiRecentscoreIdentifier)
        ]

        highscores = [
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: multipleChoiceHighScoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: imageQuizHighScoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: rightWrongHighscoreIdentifier),
            UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: emojiHighscoreIdentifier)
        ]
    }

    func layoutView() {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(contentView)

        logoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(logoView)
        logoView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")

        buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(buttonView)

        for (index,title) in titles.enumerated() {
            let button = RoundedButton()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 152/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1.0)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.tag = index
            gameButtons.append(button)
        }

        scoreView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(scoreView)

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        recentScoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        highscoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scoreView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        scoreView.addSubview(recentScoreLabel)
        scoreView.addSubview(highscoreLabel)

        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        recentScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        highscoreLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        highscoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

        titleLabel.text = titles[scoreIndex]
        recentScoreLabel.text = "Recent: " + String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: multipleChoiceRecentscoreIdentifier))
        highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: " + String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: multipleChoiceHighScoreIdentifier))

        let constraints = [
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            logoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            logoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            logoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            logoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            buttonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            buttonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            buttonView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            gameButtons[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            gameButtons[0].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[1].topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            gameButtons[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor),
            gameButtons[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor),
            gameButtons[1].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[2].topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            gameButtons[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor),
            gameButtons[1].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor),
            gameButtons[2].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[3].topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            gameButtons[2].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor),
            gameButtons[2].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor),
            gameButtons[3].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            gameButtons[3].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor),
            gameButtons[3].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor),
            gameButtons[0].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[1].heightAnchor),
            gameButtons[1].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[2].heightAnchor),
            gameButtons[2].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameButtons[3].heightAnchor),
            scoreView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            scoreView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            scoreView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recentScoreLabel.topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            recentScoreLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.leadingAnchor),
            recentScoreLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.trailingAnchor),
            recentScoreLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: highscoreLabel.topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            highscoreLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.leadingAnchor),
            highscoreLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.trailingAnchor),
            highscoreLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recentScoreLabel.heightAnchor),
            recentScoreLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: highscoreLabel.heightAnchor)
        ]

        midXConstraints = [scoreView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor)]
        leftConstraints = [scoreView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)]
        rightConstraints = [scoreView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(midXConstraints)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(nextScores), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func nextScores() {
        scoreIndex = scoreIndex < (recentScores.count - 1) ? scoreIndex + 1 : 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.midXConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.leftConstraints)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) {(completion: Bool) in
            self.titleLabel.text = self.titles[self.scoreIndex]
            self.recentScoreLabel.text  = "Recent: " + String(self.recentScores[self.scoreIndex]) //Index out of bounds error appears here
            self.highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: " + String(self.highscores[self.scoreIndex])
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.leftConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.rightConstraints)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.rightConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.midXConstraints)
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is. Why dont you log the index your calling and the available max index on self.recentScores to simply see that you are calling an outofbound index?

Answer (score 1):

The recentScores is an empty array, i.e. it has 0 elements, and you are trying to access its first element. You don't append any element to this array. That's why you get "index out of bounds" error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

`self.recentScores` count is 0 and you are trying to access `self.recentScores[0]`

```
if self.recentScores.count > 0 {
    self.recentScoreLabel.text  = "Recent: " + String(self.recentScores[self.scoreIndex]) //Index out of bounds error appears here
}
if self.highscores.count > 0 {
    self.highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: " + String(self.highscores[self.scoreIndex])
}
```